# UNABLE TO LOAD ISO8601.PM FILE IN PERL

Tags: perl

I have my ISO8601.PM under tmp location but still unable to load that file in perl script .
I have the code snippet as

```
use lib '/tmp/';
my $date = "2014-04-30T07:28:54.864Z";

my $iso8601 = DateTime::Format::ISO8601 -> new();
    my $dt = $iso8601->parse_datetime( $date );
    my $dt = $iso8601->parse_time( $date );
print "$dt\n";
```

It gives me the error as :

```
can't locate object method "new" 
      via package "DateTime::Format::ISO8601" 
      (perhaps you forgot to load "DateTime::Format::ISO8601"?) at ./date.pl line 9.
```

Comment: PS - That specific format is also known as RFC3339, so you can also use the more lightweight DateTime::Format::RFC3339. (This won't solve any of your problems.)

Answer (score 3):

your script seems to be missing the 'use DateTime::Format::ISO8601' instruction

.. so the interpreter can't find the relevent new-method and complains '*perhaps you forgot*' ..

add

```
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;
```

near the top of  your code and see if that helps!

Comment: and make sure the file is /tmp/DateTime/Format/ISO8601.pm, not /tmp/ISO8601.pm

Comment: using :use lib '/tmp/DateTime/Format/ISO8601.pm';
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601; gies error as "Can't locate DateTime/Format/ISO8601.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /tmp/DateTime/Format/ISO8601.pm /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64" NOTE: I have my ISO8601.pm file at /tmp/ location...Do I need to place in some other way??

Comment: He didn't say to change `use lib '/tmp/';` just to add `use  DateTime::Format::ISO8601`.

Comment: error:Can't locate DateTime.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /tmp/ /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at /tmp//DateTime/Format/ISO8601.pm line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /tmp//DateTime/Format/ISO8601.pm line 12.

Comment: @user3616128 maybe you need to install the `DateTime` module first. You can probably do so via the system's package manager (such as `sudo apt-get install libdatetime-perl`) or fall back to `sudo cpan DateTime`.